# Activeadmin year select has only 10 years before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a `Date` field, `date_of_birth`
on active admin resource I use
`input :date_of_birth, required: true` this gives me a dropdown for the year that has only 10 values, from 2016 to 2026.
How can I change the values for year dropdown?

Comment: Do you need the date_of_birth, or the year of birth? I think you need something like ```f.input :date_of_birth, :as => :datepicker```. If that is not sufficient please specify more details.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might build collection for the date_of_birth. For example (dirty method, I don't love it):

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :date_of_birth, as: :select, collection: YEARS_COLLECTION
  end
end
```

Where YEARS_COLLECTION might be replaced easily with mock `(1990..Date.now.year).to_a`, or be calculated in your active_admin controller, or might be fetched from the collection (if you have one): `BirthYear.all`.

Unfortunately, I can't advise anything else because I don't know what years you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The date input you're using is the default one provided by Rails. You can see the options available in the docs for [date_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select). In particular, you want:

`:start_year` - Set the start year for the year select. Default is Time.now.year - 5.

`:end_year` - Set the end year for the year select. Default is Time.now.year + 5.

So you can do this:

```
f.input :date_of_birth, start_year: 1900
```